# Can I specify or select a member of a class (and use it as parameter )?

Tags: c++, reflection, class-members

For example, let's say I have:

```
class AB { float a,b; };
```

How do I write one function that can process either `a` or `b`, based on a parameter that's passed in, in a "proper" way? I want to do something like this:

```
float getSqrt(AB x, ClassMemberSelector s) 
{ return sqrt(x.s); }

AB x;
getSqrt(x, SelectClassMember(AB::a) ); //get square root of x.a
getSqrt(x, SelectClassMember(AB::b) ); //get square root of x.b
```

Comment: You're looking for a "pointer to member" (no need for reflection). But for your example that's unnecessary complication.

Comment: True, but it's a simplified example to illustrate what I'm look for.

Answer (score 4):

Sure, here are three examples:

---

**1)**

```
float getSqrt(const AB& ab, function<float(const AB&)> selector) 
{
    return sqrt(selector(ab));
}
```

which simplifies to (thanks to [NathanOliver](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4342498/nathanoliver)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43126887/in-c-can-i-specify-or-select-a-member-of-a-class-and-use-it-as-parameter/43126986#comment73332832_43126986)):

```
template<typename SelectorT>
float getSqrt(AB ab, SelectorT selector) 
{
    return sqrt(selector(ab));
}
```

(this version is better, as it avoids copying a lambda into `std::function`)

and usage (same for both versions):

```
cout << getSqrt(x, [](const AB& ab) { return ab.a; }) << endl;
cout << getSqrt(x, [](const AB& ab) { return ab.b; }) << endl;
```

---

**2)**

Another possibility would be to use a pointer to member:

```
float getSqrt(const AB& ab, float AB::*selector)
{
    return sqrt(ab.*selector);
}
```

and usage:

```
cout << getSqrt(x, &AB::a) << endl;
cout << getSqrt(x, &AB::b) << endl;
```

---

**3)**

And an example using TMP trait-like overload selection:

```
struct SelectAMemberT {};
struct SelectBMemberT {};

template<typename SelectorT>
float getSqrt(const AB& ab, SelectorT);

template<>
float getSqrt(const AB& ab, SelectAMemberT)
{
    return sqrt(ab.a);
}

template<>
float getSqrt(const AB& ab, SelectBMemberT)
{
    return sqrt(ab.b);
}

const SelectAMemberT SelectAMember;
const SelectBMemberT SelectBMember;
```

and usage:

```
cout << getSqrt(x, SelectAMember) << endl;
cout << getSqrt(x, SelectBMember) << endl;
```

Comment: You can save yourself some dynamic memory allocation and type erasure if you make `getSqrt` a template and just make `selector` a template type.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

class AB
{
public:
    float a, b;
};

float getSqrt(AB x, float AB::*mem)
{
    return sqrt(x.*mem);
}


int main()
{
    AB x;
    x.a = 9;
    x.b = 16;
    std::cout << "sqrt x.a: " << getSqrt(x, &AB::a) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "sqrt x.b: " << getSqrt(x, &AB::b) << std::endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A little problem: your member variables need to be public.